# Docker proxy request failed

Tags: docker

I am trying to deploy a spring boot back end using mysql database and a react front end to docker.

After deploying the back end and database, they communicate well through api request.

Hoever, when I deploy the front end, I received the following error:

```
Could not proxy request from localhost:3000 to http://0.0.0.0:8080.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you post here your Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml?